# could not find a provider for the InitialContextFactory com.sonicsw.jndi.mfcontext.MFContextFactory

Tags: jms, websphere, jndi, message-driven-bean, sonicmq

I am getting this exception when i am trying to start the WAS server. I have created JMS providers in console and set all the jar files in the classpath. 
External initial context factory  defined is com.sonicsw.jndi.mfcontext.MFContextFactory with a valid URL.

I am not sure if the issue is with websphere configuration settings or code.

Can someone please provide any context to move forward?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add more information?

classpath, properties set up for your connector

check this documentation :

http://documentation.progress.com/output/Sonic/8.5.1/jca_books/resadapwas_guide.pdf

regards